# How to compare two dates in MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to compare two date in sql statement like following:

```
$before_5_days = date("d.m.Y", strtotime( '-5 days' ) );
$GLOBALS['db']->query("DELETE FROM matches_of_comments WHERE flag=1 AND match_date >'$before_5_days'");
```

the above query delete wrong fields.

the match_date column is in varchar and i can not change it , i want to compare it with $before_5_days in the same format . is there any function like "strtotime" that could be used in the query to change the type of the match_date and make the comparison???

Comment: how about [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and DATE_SUB()

Comment: This can be done but the answer depends on the date's format. Please describe the date's format in the `VARCHAR` column - is it `MM/DD/YYYY`? `YYYY-MM-DD`? Something else?

Comment: it is d.m.Y like 27.08.2013

Answer (score 0):

> DELETE FROM matches_of_comments WHERE flag=1 AND
>   DATE_FORMAT(match_date, '%Y-%m-%d') > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -5
>   DAY)

Answer (score 0):

You could use date_format and str_to_date, for your needs i think this will work:

```
DELETE FROM matches_of_comments WHERE flag=1 AND date_format(STR_TO_DATE(match_date,'%d.%m.%Y'), '%d.%m.%Y') > '$before_5_days'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in MySQL; no need to do any PHP date math:

```
DELETE FROM matches_of_comments
WHERE flag = 1
  AND STR_TO_DATE(match_date, '%d.%m.%Y') > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 DAY;
```

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` bases "5 days ago" on the date *and* time. To base it on date only, use `CURDATE()` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
DELETE FROM matches_of_comments
WHERE flag = 1
  AND STR_TO_DATE(match_date, '%d.%m.%Y') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY;
```

Comment: I try to use this solution with CURDATE() but it does not work. I try to use select instead of delete so it gave me all the dates.in the table

Comment: The `WHERE` clause should find the same rows whether you're doing a `DELETE` or an `INSERT`. It could be that I misunderstood your date format. Could you give me an *exact* example of two of the dates in your table: one that's within the past five days and one that isn't?

Comment: can u check this question please                                      stackoverflow.com/questions/18592395/how-to-subtracte-a-value-from-the-curdate/

Comment: That question will also need you to show some actual date values from your table. Since it's newer it has a better chance of being answered, so could you add the sample dates there?